# What happens with MFC dialog form after OK button click

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

What happens with `MFC` dialog form when I click `OK` button. Looks like it is not destroyed since it's constructor was not executed.  I have pointer to this form `StatusDlg * statusDlg;`. How to know this form is not visible? How to use this form once again and show to user? 
How to destroy this form completely?

I create it like:

```
statusDlg = new StatusDlg(NULL);
statusDlg->Create(StatusDlg::IDD,CWnd::GetDesktopWindow());
statusDlg->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
```

And when it is created I press OK.

Comment: After you created it, what did you do next?  Were you expecting it to display?

Comment: Show more code.

Comment: *"How to know this form is not visible?"* - Chances are, that [CWnd::IsWindowVisible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/49a832ee-bc34-4126-88b3-bc1d9974f6c4.aspx#cwnd__iswindowvisible) will return that information. And, as I have explained many times before, you cannot possibly hope to become proficient with MFC without intimate familiarity with the Windows API. You will keep stumbling across tiny and tiniest problems (like this one). Not knowing how to use a debugger isn't going to prove helpful either.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "it's constructor was not executed"...  I assume you meant to say that it's destructor was not executed.

That would be true.

Eventually, what happens is that the API function `EndDialog(m_hWwnd, IDOK)` gets called on your dialog.  That causes your dialog to be hidden.

However, the window handle of the dialog and it's pointer is still valid.  On program termination, the window will be destroyed but your C++ destructor will still never be called.  If you want to ensure your destructor is called, overried PostNcDestroy() like this:

```
void StatusDlg::PostNcDestroy()
{
   __super::PostNcDestroy();// might be able to be skipped if baseclass does nothing, which I suspect is the case
   delete this; // deletes this StatusDlg
}
```

Your statusDlg pointer can tell you whether the window is visible.  Just call `statusDlg->IsWindowVisible()`--assuming you hang onto the statusDlg pointer somewhere.

If you override PostNcDestroy() like I did, then you **NEVER** want to make a call like:

```
delete statusDlg; // bad things will happen... (attempted double deletion)
```

Instead, you want to do this:

```
statusDlg->DestroyWindow(); // PostNcDestroy() takes care of deletion
```

What I said above holds true for modeless dialogs.  For modal dialogs, it is done slightly different.

Comment: *"That causes your dialog to be hidden. However, the window handle of the dialog [...] is still valid."* - That's not correct. [EndDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645472.aspx) causes the native dialog object to be destroyed (which invalidates its `HWND` as well). Your workaround is fairly brittle, too, and I wouldn't recommend it. Instead, you should control object lifetime through the C++ class (i.e. **do** use `delete statusDlg;` when it's no longer needed).

Comment: Respectfully, you're wrong.  I know because I wrote a little test app--in VS 2013 (and I doubt it has changed).  For a modeless MFC dialog, the window handle is still valid after the window is closed.  The window is not destroyed until the end of the process.  I know because I set a breakpoint in PostNcDestroy() and it does not get called until application termination.

You can call it brittle if you want, but it is the same thing MFC does for CView and CFrameWnd classes.

Comment: Are you saying, that the API documentation for [EndDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645472.aspx) is wrong? Or did you misrepresent the fact, that it did get called, when it really didn't?

Comment: I did not misrepresent anything.  I am not sure the Win32 API `EndDialog()` was meant to be called from a modeless dialog.  However, it is called from within MFC.  The `CDialog::OnOK()` calls `CDialog::EndDialog()` which calls the API version of `EndDialog()` after killing the modal loop (of which there isn't in a modeless dialog).

Comment: First sentence in the Remarks section of the documentation for [EndDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645472.aspx): *"Dialog boxes created by the DialogBox, DialogBoxParam, DialogBoxIndirect, and DialogBoxIndirectParam functions must be destroyed using the EndDialog function."* So yes, you need to call `EndDialog` for modeless dialogs.

Comment: DId I say `EndDIalog()` does not need to be called?  But, if you dig in the MFC source code, the API used to create a modeless dialog is 'CreateDialogIndirect()'--which is none of the functions listed in the documentation for `EndDialog()`.

In fact, even for "modal" MFC dialogs, they aren't quite normal modal API dialogs.  MFC creates them as modeless API dialogs and then sets up its own modal loop.  That is the modal loop that `CDialog::EndDialog()` kills before it calls the API `EndDialog()`.

Comment: The original poster has not even replied to the help he has bene provided. Disappointing. He may not even understand the concept of **modeless** dialogues where you have to **destroy** it yourself.